# Spring integration test, prevent redirect to be able to compare status code

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test

I'm trying to do integration tests to my Spring-boot app. I have a protected endpoint (/uaa/change_password, Spring MVC), which redirects to /uaa/login when not authenticated. How can I intercept that request I send, I only get back a 200 OK for /uaa/login page. So the test fails for `assertEquals(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, response.getStatusCode());` Since the status code is 200. (The other test also fails). Any help appreciated.

Code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ApiAuthServerApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest("server.port:0")
public class ApiAuthServerApplicationTests {

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    private int port;

    private RestTemplate template = new TestRestTemplate();

    @Test
    public void changePasswordPageProtected() {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = template.getForEntity("http://localhost:"
                + port + "/uaa/change_password", String.class);

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, response.getStatusCode());
        String auth = response.getHeaders().getFirst("WWW-Authenticate");
        assertTrue("Wrong header: " + auth, auth.startsWith("Bearer realm"));
    }
}
```

My config:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {          
        http
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .and()
            .requestMatchers().antMatchers(                     
                    "/login", 
                    "/oauth/authorize",                     
                    "/oauth/confirm_access", 
                    "/reset_password", 
                    "/forgot_password",
                    "/change_password")     
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/reset_password", "/forgot_password").permitAll()             
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable automatic redirect in `RestTemplate`. I recommend [`Apache HTTP Client`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) for that purpose.

Below you'll find an example how to configure `RestTemplate` in order to not follow `HTTP 302`:

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;

....

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().disableRedirectHandling().build();
new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));
```

Comment: Actually I just needed to add testCompile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1') to my gradle build, so it's available on the classpath. Thanks to @ksokol for the guidance.